# STM32F4 as I2C Slave. Why "void I2C1_ER_IRQHandler(void)" is executed after "HAL_I2C_Slave_Transmit_DMA"?

Tags: c, stm32, i2c, dma, stm32f4

I am using I2C bus as SLAVE mode in a STM32F411RE. The master is an arduino board.

The configuration is working well because I see thougth master serial (arduino) and STstudio (STM32F411) that all the frames are OK and thrue oscilloscope.

I noticed that I2C1_ER_IRQHandler function is triggered every time the slave finishes its TX transmission (Master receive that transmision and finishes with NACK and STOP BIT). In the next link:

https://drive.google.com/file/d/1-W5Z2nsvLNj6PE1TT9eDCDdYvFpnis8g/view?usp=sharing
https://drive.google.com/file/d/14JkeAw2If3v0A71V9-KQasH9rK3PRm3H/view?usp=sharing
https://drive.google.com/file/d/1Te2F8aNnvkqUSnfRK5UOO-qKabLXXv1D/view?usp=sharing

you can download pictures, you can see the SDA signal and GPIO PIN 2 which toggles within I2C1_ER_IRQHandler function. ¿could be related to the Slave (stm32) is receiving NACK at the end of thanssmission? see pictures

The SLAVE main function and calls are as follows:

```
#define BUFFERSIZE_RX      0x03    // Master sends 3 bytes
#define BUFFERSIZE_TX      0x04    //Master is waiting for 4 bytes

uint8_t aRxBuffer[BUFFERSIZE_RX];
uint8_t aTxBuffer[BUFFERSIZE_TX];

int main(void)
{
…uC INITIALIZATION

    if(HAL_I2C_Slave_Receive_DMA(&hi2c1, (uint8_t *)aRxBuffer, BUFFERSIZE_RX) != HAL_OK)
    {
        Error_Handler();
    }
    while (1)
    {}
}

void HAL_I2C_SlaveTxCpltCallback(I2C_HandleTypeDef *hi2c)
{
    if(HAL_I2C_GetState(&hi2c1) == HAL_I2C_STATE_READY)
    {
        if(HAL_I2C_Slave_Receive_DMA(&hi2c1, (uint8_t *)aRxBuffer, BUFFERSIZE_RX) != HAL_OK)
        {
            Error_Handler();
        }
    }
}

void HAL_I2C_SlaveRxCpltCallback(I2C_HandleTypeDef *hi2c)      
{
    if(HAL_I2C_GetState(&hi2c1) == HAL_I2C_STATE_READY)
    {
        if(HAL_I2C_Slave_Transmit_DMA(&hi2c1, (uint8_t*)aTxBuffer, BUFFERSIZE_TX)!= HAL_OK)
        {
           Error_Handler();
        }
    }
}

void HAL_I2C_ErrorCallback(I2C_HandleTypeDef *hi2c)
{
    HAL_GPIO_WritePin(GPIOA, GPIO_PIN_3, GPIO_PIN_SET);
}

void I2C1_ER_IRQHandler(void)
{
 HAL_I2C_ER_IRQHandler(&hi2c1);
 HAL_GPIO_TogglePin(GPIOA, GPIO_PIN_2);
}
```

I2C and DMA configuration is as the STM32Cube_FW_F4_V1.24.0 examples, but if you need them I can send them as well.

The Arduino Master only sends the following functions:

```
void loop()
{       
    Wire.beginTransmission(address);
    Wire.write((uint8_t)M_TX_1);
    Wire.write((uint8_t)M_TX_2);
    Wire.write((uint8_t)M_TX_3);
    Wire.endTransmission();
    delay(1);
    Wire.requestFrom(address, (uint8_t)4);
    M_RX_1 = Wire.read();
    M_RX_2 = Wire.read();      
    M_RX_3 = Wire.read();
    M_RX_4 = Wire.read();
… Serial prints and so on…     
}
```

I have tested I2C in interruption mode and the same thing happens… communications works but always the I2C1_ER_IRQHandler is called.

I am completely lost, any help or comment are really appreciate!!!

Sorry for the long post.

P.D. HAL_I2C_ErrorCallback never called, so i suppose that it is OK.

Best regards.

Alejandro

PD2: SPI GPIO and DMA configuration:

```
static void MX_I2C1_Init(void)
{
    hi2c1.Instance = I2C1;
    hi2c1.Init.ClockSpeed = 100000;
    //hi2c1.Init.DutyCycle = I2C_DUTYCYCLE_2;
    hi2c1.Init.DutyCycle = I2C_DUTYCYCLE_16_9;  // Modificacion
    hi2c1.Init.OwnAddress1 = SLAVEADDRESS << 1; // Modificacion
    hi2c1.Init.AddressingMode = I2C_ADDRESSINGMODE_7BIT;
    hi2c1.Init.DualAddressMode = I2C_DUALADDRESS_DISABLE;
    hi2c1.Init.OwnAddress2 = 0;
    //hi2c1.Init.OwnAddress2 = 0x06;        // Modificacion
    hi2c1.Init.GeneralCallMode = I2C_GENERALCALL_DISABLE;
    hi2c1.Init.NoStretchMode = I2C_NOSTRETCH_DISABLE;
    if (HAL_I2C_Init(&hi2c1) != HAL_OK)
    {
    Error_Handler();
    }
}

static void MX_DMA_Init(void) 
{
    __HAL_RCC_DMA1_CLK_ENABLE();

    HAL_NVIC_SetPriority(DMA1_Stream0_IRQn, 0, 1);
    HAL_NVIC_EnableIRQ(DMA1_Stream0_IRQn);
    HAL_NVIC_SetPriority(DMA1_Stream1_IRQn, 0, 2);
    HAL_NVIC_EnableIRQ(DMA1_Stream1_IRQn);
}

void HAL_I2C_MspInit(I2C_HandleTypeDef* hi2c)
{
  GPIO_InitTypeDef GPIO_InitStruct = {0};
  if(hi2c->Instance==I2C1)
  {
    __HAL_RCC_GPIOB_CLK_ENABLE();

    GPIO_InitStruct.Pin = GPIO_PIN_6|GPIO_PIN_7;
    GPIO_InitStruct.Mode = GPIO_MODE_AF_OD;
    GPIO_InitStruct.Pull = GPIO_PULLUP;
    GPIO_InitStruct.Speed = GPIO_SPEED_FREQ_VERY_HIGH;
    GPIO_InitStruct.Alternate = GPIO_AF4_I2C1;
    HAL_GPIO_Init(GPIOB, &GPIO_InitStruct);

    __HAL_RCC_I2C1_CLK_ENABLE();

    hdma_i2c1_rx.Instance = DMA1_Stream0;
    hdma_i2c1_rx.Init.Channel = DMA_CHANNEL_1;
    hdma_i2c1_rx.Init.Direction = DMA_PERIPH_TO_MEMORY;
    hdma_i2c1_rx.Init.PeriphInc = DMA_PINC_DISABLE;
    hdma_i2c1_rx.Init.MemInc = DMA_MINC_ENABLE;
    hdma_i2c1_rx.Init.PeriphDataAlignment = DMA_PDATAALIGN_BYTE;
    hdma_i2c1_rx.Init.MemDataAlignment = DMA_MDATAALIGN_BYTE;
    hdma_i2c1_rx.Init.Mode = DMA_NORMAL;
    hdma_i2c1_rx.Init.Priority = DMA_PRIORITY_LOW;
    hdma_i2c1_rx.Init.FIFOMode = DMA_FIFOMODE_DISABLE;
    hdma_i2c1_rx.Init.FIFOThreshold = DMA_FIFO_THRESHOLD_FULL;  
    hdma_i2c1_rx.Init.MemBurst = DMA_MBURST_INC4;               
    hdma_i2c1_rx.Init.PeriphBurst = DMA_PBURST_INC4;    
    if (HAL_DMA_Init(&hdma_i2c1_rx) != HAL_OK)
    {
        Error_Handler();
    }
    __HAL_LINKDMA(hi2c,hdmarx,hdma_i2c1_rx);

    hdma_i2c1_tx.Instance = DMA1_Stream1;
    hdma_i2c1_tx.Init.Channel = DMA_CHANNEL_0;
    hdma_i2c1_tx.Init.Direction = DMA_MEMORY_TO_PERIPH;
    hdma_i2c1_tx.Init.PeriphInc = DMA_PINC_DISABLE;
    hdma_i2c1_tx.Init.MemInc = DMA_MINC_ENABLE;
    hdma_i2c1_tx.Init.PeriphDataAlignment = DMA_PDATAALIGN_BYTE;
    hdma_i2c1_tx.Init.MemDataAlignment = DMA_MDATAALIGN_BYTE;
    hdma_i2c1_tx.Init.Mode = DMA_NORMAL;
    hdma_i2c1_tx.Init.Priority = DMA_PRIORITY_HIGH;
    hdma_i2c1_tx.Init.FIFOMode = DMA_FIFOMODE_DISABLE;
    hdma_i2c1_tx.Init.FIFOThreshold = DMA_FIFO_THRESHOLD_FULL;              
    hdma_i2c1_tx.Init.MemBurst = DMA_MBURST_INC4;           
    hdma_i2c1_tx.Init.PeriphBurst = DMA_PBURST_INC4;
    if (HAL_DMA_Init(&hdma_i2c1_tx) != HAL_OK)
    {
        Error_Handler();
    }

    __HAL_LINKDMA(hi2c,hdmatx,hdma_i2c1_tx);

    HAL_NVIC_SetPriority(I2C1_EV_IRQn, 0, 3);
    HAL_NVIC_EnableIRQ(I2C1_EV_IRQn);
    HAL_NVIC_SetPriority(I2C1_ER_IRQn, 0, 2);
    HAL_NVIC_EnableIRQ(I2C1_ER_IRQn);
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

To start with,   Is it possible that this is an event IRQ (EV) to indicate a slave has finished transferring data and is not an error IRQ?  You may have configured this to show that the slave is done with data transfer on the bus.

If that is not the case, definitely take a little better look at the I2C standard of communication.  In your case, a NACK just indicates the stop of the transfer all together from the master, or it could mean that the transfer failed, but if you say all frames are successful, then it is definitely the end of transfer condition. 
That being said, it is important to know how this was all configured.  I would check the initialization sequence of the I2C on the F4 and make sure that it is in compliance with what is expected from the Arduino.  It should be something like this.

1. Setup the associated clocks with I2C and GPIOs
2. Map the GPIOs
3. Enable the Interrupt services needed through the Nested Vectored Interrupt Controller (NVIC)
4. Set the settings of the I2C to the desired framing
5. Enable the I2C peripheral and interrupts

These steps will allow you to make sure you are covering your ground here.

Now you also must make sure you have the right features enabled if you are using DMA with I2C as well. The F4 does some packet error checking after the end of each message.  Do you have the PEC enabled? If so, make sure there is not something causing this to get the IRQ interrupt to fire.

You also have event flags to read from in a debugger to see what error specifically triggered the I2C IRQ error line.  According to the STMF4 reference manual, the event flags to generate an interrupt are:

```
0: Error interrupt disabled
1: Error interrupt enabled
This interrupt is generated when:
– BERR = 1
– ARLO = 1
– AF = 1
– OVR = 1
– PECERR = 1
– TIMEOUT = 1
– SMBALERT = 1
```

Although, you mentioned that the Error Callback function was not active, so these might not be present.

Finally, just to be safe, ensure the IRQ line isn't being used elsewhere in software.  it could just be that the line is controlled by something else and being pulled high, causing the IRQ handler function to be called.  This is unlikely if the code you posted is the only thing running, but it is worth a thought.

Comment: Thanks for quick reply!! I generate the configuration using CubeMX, nevertheless, I edited the question adding DMA, I2C and I2C GPIO configuration, just in case i miss something.  I am checking the event flags you mentioned. Related to HAL_I2C_ErrorCallback, yes, it is never called. Regards.

Comment: I have just checked that the event flag which is triggering the I2C1_ER_IRQHandler function  is AF (ACK FAILURE). I supose when the TX slave transmission finished, the Master send a NACK (which is normal) but the STM32 looks like that it is waitting for an ACK?? It is not normal... Here you can download the captures from IDE: https://drive.google.com/file/d/1I6S88PUNvTxBudIVt_l8WzK46Li9xBFm/view?usp=sharing
https://drive.google.com/file/d/16kVjkWb_D2yZo6w-Zfr_Vo0gmZQHEyaf/view?usp=sharing . How can I solve the problem?? I have modify all I2C configuration posibilities and DMA with none result

Comment: The HAL can be finicky at times with things like this.  One thing you could do is hard-code this feature in if you really want it.  By that, I mean set up a GPIO line and hook up an interrupt when the line is driven high, and you can watch the last piece of the transfer for the NACK, if you get something else, you know an error is there and can drive the line high.  Or, you could just disable the error event interrupt by removing the code for it.  You can just depend on the HAL return type to determine an error, which is not uncommon.